# gradle won't pick specified jvm

Tags: gradle

`/home/user/gradle-5.6.4/bin/gradle -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/home/user/java11/jdk-11.0.2 -version`

Output

```
Gradle 5.6.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-01 20:42:00 UTC
Revision:     dd870424f9bd8e195d614dc14bb140f43c22da98

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_252 (Private Build 25.252-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-106-generic amd64
```

Why is it picking 1.8.0_252?

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
>   feedback for so

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `-Dorg.gradle.java.home` does not override JAVA_HOME

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
```